# Failed to find cpu0 device node at every boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.7 RC6 and at every boot I got the message: Failed to find cpu0 device node.
It is something to fix or is nothing important ?!

Can you help me ?!

Thanks in advance.

Bye

Luca Tansini

Comment: Do you get the same with kernel 4.7-rc4? There were huge huge kernel configuration changes between 4.7-rc4 and 4.7-rc5, but no changes between -rc5 and -rc6. Note: Someone will probably vote to close this, as development kernels are not supported here. If that happens, we always have a [development kernel](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326220) thread going over on Ubuntu forums, try there.

Comment: Yes, I get the problem from 4.7RC4 to 4.7RC5

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying the problem does not exist when you use kernel 4.7-rc4, but the problem does exist when you use kernel 4.7-rc5? Or are you saying that both kernels, 4.7-rc4 and 4.7-rc5 have the same error message as kernel 4.7-rc6? Do you have the ability to compile the kernel yourself?

Comment: Yes, the message at boot come out from RC4 and RC5 and now I am at RC7 is still there. I have the ability to compile the kernel, but normally I am waiting that from the linux kernel mainline I can find the 3 file *.deb to install the kernel more easily than compile it.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to start narrowing down and isolate the kernel configuration change that causes the problem. It might take quite awhile, involving many kernel compiles. We might be able to think carefully about it, and narrow down the list of kernel configuration changes. I am willing to help, but will be away this week, and can only help starting next weekend.

Comment: No problem, Thanks you Doug, when you want I am waiting for your help.

Comment: Luca: Which architecture type of the kernel are you using? 32 bit or 64 bit or low latency or? The message is printed from /drivers/base/cacheinfo.c and only if CONFIG_OF is set, which on my amd64 kernels it wasn't set in 4.6-rc4 or 4.6-rc5 (or rc6 or rc7). Is it set on your kernels? ( example: `grep CONFIG_OF /boot/config-4.7.0-040700rc4-generic`) Does your system work O.K. other than this message? It might be O.K. to ignore the message.

Comment: Thanks Doug, my kernel in 32-bit and is set to generic. The System is not affected by the message at boot or it seems.

Comment: Failed to find cpu0 device node still present at every boot. Now my generic kernel version is 4.8-RC6, but the message of finding cpu0 failed still remain even if doesn't make any problem. I am just feed up to keep on seeing this message every boot since four months.

Comment: For Doug: I check my config file about the kernel I am using now and the CONFIF_OF is not present in the file.

Comment: Now I'm at Kernel Version 4.8.0 and the message is still there at boot: Failed to find cpu0 device node. Anybody have found a solution. My distribution is Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance for any advices. Bye Bye. Luca Tansini

Comment: Problem solved with kernel 4.8.3